# Kendo Scheduler in a Kendo Mobile App

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to get the new kendo scheduler widget to work in a kendo mobile application. As soon as I switch views (Go from month to week), it crashes. Same code works great on Chrome and Firefox. The error in logcat is

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/app/frameworks/kendoui/js/kendo.all.min.js:30

Comment: This only happens when the scheduler is set to "editable: false"

Comment: Could it be because your trying it on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but I ran into this issue today. It seems like if you set the individual "editables" to `false` you get the same results without the error.

So instead of:

```
editable: false
```

try using:

```
editable: {
  create: false,
  destroy: false,
  resize: false,
  update: false
}
```